# How to specify figure position in latex

Tags: floats, positioning

I need to place the figure under a specific paragraph but it appears at a randome position. Can you please modify my code using the appropriate command?
Thanks

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \graphicspath{Figures/}
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{Figures/capacitor.jpg}
  \caption{Capacitor...}
  \label{Capacitor 1}
  \end{figure}
```

Comment: If you don't want your image to float (move away from where it was specified in the code) do not use the `figure` environmnent. To nevertheless add a caption to your image, you can make use of the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package.

Comment: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/134144) might also be worth having a look at.

Comment: it is not a random position but the only purpose of the `figure`  environment is to specify that it is a float that may be moved to help page breaking.